# Update ImageBrush from ResourceDictionary at runtime

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

In my WP7 application, all the pages use an ImageBrush as the background that I have defined in a ResourceDictionay. This ResourceDictionary is merged globally through the App.xaml. The ImageBrush in the ResourceDictionary is defined like this:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="PhonePageBackground" ImageSource="/Background1.jpg"/>
```

Im trying to update the ImageSource of the ImageBrush at runtime, but its not working.

Making some tests, where I have a page with a button on it to change the background, I realized that the code below works fine:

```
    ImageBrush image;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        image = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Background1.jpg", UriKind.Relative)) };

        LayoutRoot.Background = image;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Background2.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

But the code below, where I use the ImageBrush from the dictionary, does not work. The background of the page becomes transparent, as if the image could not be found:

```
    ImageBrush image;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        image = (ImageBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhonePageBackground"];

        LayoutRoot.Background = image;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        image.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Background2.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Both images (Background1.jpg and Background2.jpg) build action are set as Content. I've tested with Resource set, but without success.

Any knowledge of why this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
ImageBrush image; 
         public MainPage()                
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            image = (ImageBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhonePageBackground"];
            LayoutRoot.Background = image; 
        }


private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            image = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Background2.jpg",  UriKind.Relative)) };
            LayoutRoot.Background = image;
    }
```

Comment: This works indeed, but its not what Im trying to accomplish. You're updating the LayoutRoot.Background but not the ImageBrush in the resource dictionary. I want that both the background and the ImageBrush resource be updated. The issue has been solved in my other post [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/102679.aspx)